# overwrite stringbuilder

Tags: c#, regex, stringbuilder

I am reading text from a file into a string builder, I make a quick replacement using .Replace(), then I need to run two regex against the string builder to completely overwrite the string builder.  What is the best way to do this?

I used Append to initially load the StringBuilder from the streamreader, then used .Replace() for the simple replacement.  Now I need to remove the beginning and end of each line based on two different regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to convert the `StringBuilder` into a string (calling its `ToString()` method) and perform the Regex operations on the string.

Also if you are just interested in reading all text from a file, you don't need to use a stream and a `StringBuilder`, instead just use `File.ReadAllText(someFile)` which returns a string, or `File.ReadAllLines(someFile)` which returns a string array .

Comment: Thanks Broken, What is the most efficient way to get the result of the regex back into the stringbuilder?  I need to overwrite the stringbuilder with the regex result.

Comment: why do you need it back as a StringBuilder? If you truely do just create a new StringBuilder with the string returned by the regex result